# Unable to setup pycharm geo viewer, enable JCEF setting unavailable

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, postgis

Has anyone used the geo viewer in pycharm? I was looking for an equivalent to the vscode geo data viewer extension and found this [documentation.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tables-view-data.html#using-geo-viewer-for-spatial-data) However, when following the steps I cannot find the settings for JCEF anywhere, and clicking the search for geo viewer doesn't open anything.
[No JCEF in web settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAfBk.png)
[No 'Show Geo Viewer' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNgQY.png)

I'm on the latest windows version of pycharm pro connected via SSH to an ubuntu machine with PostgreSQL and PostGIS set up and installed. I've restarted and confirmed PostGIS extension. Looking for any guidance as to possible required dependencies I'm missing or how to set up use of geo viewer.

Looking around I haven't found literally anything on Pycharm's geo viewer which I found quite surprising. I searched for all the settings within pycharm and show geo viewer pops up but doesn't open. Chatgpt says I need to enable JCEF in web browsers and preview but JCEF is not listed there. I saw for intelliJ JCEF is enabled by default in newer versions so maybe that is the case for pycharm? Any suggestions appreciated.